# How should Firebase custom claims be added from App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase-authentication

Using App Engine (Java) to add custom claims to a user's Firebase token as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims).  I'm using the [Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/authorizing-apps#application_default_credentials) as my project owner account.  Running `gcloud auth list` shows that the correct account is active.

I've configured my Firebase settings in the app as follows:

```java
// Error handling and try/catches omitted
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault())
                    .setProjectId("<my-app>")
                    .setDatabaseUrl("https://<my-app>.firebaseio.com/")
                    .build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

Once this is set, I use the following code adapted from the example [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims).

```java
Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
claims.put("role", "admin");
fbInstance.setCustomUserClaims(usersFirebaseAccessToken, claims);
```

This throws the following error:

> Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from the Google Cloud SDK or Google Cloud Shell which are not supported by the identitytoolkit.googleapis.com. We recommend that most server applications use service accounts instead. For more information about service accounts and how to use them in your application, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/.

After seeing this, I reverted to the standard service account approach where instead of `GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()`, I used `ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccountStream)` where `serviceAccountStream = new FileInputStream("path-to-service-account-file")`.  This complained about insufficient privileges despite having the `Firebase Admin` group in GCP IAM settings.  The real issue, though, is that the Identity Toolkit docs [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/) mention that the Identity Toolkit is being replaced by Firebase Authentication, which seemed to be the approach I was originally trying.

I'm interested to know what the error message above means by "end user".  This seems to suggest that the GCP SDK is trying to authenticate as the user represented by the Firebase token but I'm almost certain this isn't what it means.

Is there something I'm missing in my Firebase config that's causing the system to think I'm the wrong user?